# How to get the x509 certificate encoding type in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to read a certificate for a remote host using Java. I want to get the encoding type. I typed:

```
    System.out.println("The encoding is: "+ x509Cert.getEncoded().toString());
```

The output I get is:

```
The encoding is: [B@597c3925
```

What is the problem ?

EDIT: x509Cert is an object of type X509Certificate.

Comment: That method returns the encoded *data,* not the encoding type, and calling toString() on it just returns the result of byte[].toString(), which contains neither the data nor the encoding type. The encoding type of the data returned by that method is specified in the Javadoc: it isn't dynamic; so you don't need to ascertain it at runtime at all. Not a real question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Certificate.getEncoded` returns `byte[]`, because it gives you a binary representation of the certificate data (DER in the case of X509 certificates), not text. If you want it in PEM format then that is the DER form encoded using MIME-style base 64 (you can use [Apache commons codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64Chunked%28byte%5B%5D%29) for this) and with the familiar begin and end lines added.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you some insight as to what the problem was: the object (array, in this case) obtained from `x509Cert.getEncoded()` does not override the `toString` method, so it defaults to `getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`, as defined in the `Object`-class.

And just as a note, when you do

```
"some string" + someObj.toString()
```

you don't actually need to call `toString` - it will be called on its own. You could just do

```
"some string" + someObj
```

Comment: Can you clarify to me how can I solve my issue using my example above ?